# Как поменять место поиска кодов в NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Я недавно перенес пользовательские папки на диск D. NetBeans ищет их на диске C(Проекты были в папке документы,я перенес эту папку и др.).
Что мне делать?!!!!!!

[image: Вот код ошибки:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение, при создании нового проекта откроется окно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо в поле отмеченное красным ввести "C:\Users\Имя пользователя\Documents",или нажать обзор.